# How do I use client.send_file discord.py

Tags: python, bots, discord, unauthorized, discord.py

```
@my_bot.command()
async def memes():
    await client.send_file(discord.Object(id='321332957690331138'),'1.jpg')
```

I used that and I got error code 401 aka Unauthorized

```
my_bot.run(TOKEN)
```

I'm using that to login
All my other commands work and do not output this error.
-I'm quite new to this website so I may have done something wrong-

Comment: I added 'return' to my first block of code before await. to no avail because I noticed my other commands included that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that you need to pass a proper destination (channel in server) as the first parameter. To get the server object from a server ID you can use:

`server = client.get_server('321332957690331138')`

and to get the default channel of that server you can use:

`server.default_channel`

So to sum it up you now have:

```
await client.send_file(client.get_server('321332957690331138').default_channel, '1.jpg')
```

Hope I helped!