# Regarding discord.py's send_file()

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I've been messing around with the discord.py function send_file().

I originially used this question's answer to get a basic understanding of the parameters I would need: [How do I use client.send_file discord.py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44398114/how-do-i-use-client-send-file-discord-py)

However I am planning on using my bot on a couple servers, not just one, and the answer given in the question linked above essentially hard codes a specific channel to send files to.

What I'm trying to do is have my bot get the id of the channel in which it's given the !moe command, and send a file to the same channel.

```
@client.command()
async def moe():

    await client.send_file(client.get_server('How do I get the ID of the discord channel that calls this command?')),'moe.gif')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're using the `rewrite` branch (which, iirc, you should be), it's as simple as taking a `ctx` parameter to your command's function and [accessing `ctx.channel`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/faq.html#how-do-i-get-the-original-message) (note that the docs example seems to contradict what it says before it, but in fact it's just shorthand). If you are *not* using the `rewrite` branch, I believe it should be pretty much the same process, but your decorator should look like this instead:

```
@client.command(pass_context=True)
```

Comment: I tried calling ctx.channel and ran into an error. I downloaded my discord.py files from here: https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py

Is that not the right download?

Comment: You shouldn't really use the download button on GitHub. You should be using `pip`, which should come standard with any Python installation.

Comment: If you just downloaded the `async` branch, though, then you're probably not on `rewrite`. Regardless, you haven't actually added a `ctx` parameter. Add that to your function definition first, then try `ctx.channel`. If that doesn't work, you may need to go all out with `ctx.message.channel`.

Comment: That turned out to work! Thanks! On another note, how should I go about installing the rewrite branch of discord.py?

Comment: @sg1simmons My apologies for the late reply. The `rewrite` branch is more for testing, I suppose, so you should probably be prepared to face issues with it and report them to the author as they come up. If you still want to install it, use the following command: `pip install -U git+https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py@rewrite` (assuming you've sorted out `pip`)